# AWS Cognito Custom Attributes Not Created

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to setup a Cognito user using the AWS Cognito SDK and am having trouble adding custom attributes to a user. I have ensured that the variable names match up exactly and that the application allows read/write on all of the attributes. My code looks like this:

```
var attributeList = [];

var dataName = {
    Name: 'name',
    Value: name
};
var dataPhoneNumber = {
    Name: 'phone_number',
    Value: phone
};
var dataIsDriver = {
    Name: 'custom:is_driver',
    Value: 0
};

var attributeName = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataName);
var attributePhoneNumber = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);
var attributeIsDriver = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataIsDriver);


attributeList.push(attributeName);
attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);
attributeList.push(attributeIsDriver);

var username = generateUUID();
localStorage.setItem("username", username);

var userPool = getUserPool();
userPool.signUp(username, password, attributeList, null, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
        return;
    }
}
```

With this code, the name and phone_number attributes are being set correctly but there is no "is_driver." I've tried to use adminGetUser to get all of the user's attributes but is_driver still doesn't appear. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Check the Application page in the cognito userpool. Although you mentioned that read/write permissions are given but sometimes if you add some attributes later the permission are not automatically applied. I had faced a similar issue.
Go to your user pool then select Apps > Show Details  > Set attribute read and write permissions .
Check the scope and read write permissions over there.

Comment: I've already verified that the boxes are checked: http://imgur.com/a/EvWqT. Also, the custom attributes are not showing up on the user screen: http://imgur.com/a/O3fqj. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that might be happening because you are passing the attribute value as a number so 0. It's just a particularity of the service that attributes are treated as Strings for validation.

Can you try replacing that with the code below and see if it works.

```
var dataIsDriver = {
    Name: 'custom:is_driver',
    Value: '0'
};
```